# Difference between && and || in c and unix shells?

Tags: c, shell, unix, operators

what is the difference between these operators in C and in unix shells? In C doesn't the && mean do the first process and if it is true do the second process? How would it be different in unix shells? Thanks

edit i don't mean the difference between && and ||, but rather how they differ in c language and in unix shells.

Comment: Beyond the precedence differences described by @chepner, `&&` and `||` are short-circuiting evaluation operators in both languages. That people don't use `&&` for flow control around operations performed for their side effects in C is a matter of convention, not a matter of language differences; you *could* use them that way in C if you wanted to, people would just look at you oddly (and reject your patches if they had any sense of good style).

Comment: ...point being that they're not as different as this question seems to presuppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precedence is one big difference.

Consider the following:

```
a || b && c
```

In `C`, if `a` is true, neither `b` nor `c` need to be evaluated, since the expression is parsed as `a || (b && c)`. However, in shell,

```
true || false && echo foo
```

will output `foo`, since it is parsed the same as `(a || b) && c`.

---

Also, keep in mind that some shells (like `bash`) have two uses for `&&` and `||`. In addition to being used to construct lists of commands as described above, they can also be used as C-style boolean operators to combine conditional expressions inside a `[[ ... ]]` command.

Comment: more like "short circuit evaluation" is the big difference.

Comment: Yeah, I think I messed up the example. In vaguer terms until I can get a good example, `&&` has higher precedence in `C` than `||`, but the two have equal precedence in shell.

Comment: OK, I think I've chosen a better example now.